# Reset a ScrollView to top

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I know this question is a little bit old, but I can't solve this question.Need help.
I have a UIScrollView and I want to reset this view to the top whenever I upload a photo But I failed.

I have already tried this code

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated; {

  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
//  [[self newSnapView] scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:NO];
// [[self newSnapView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
// [[self newSanpView] setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]];
}
```

It will not pop to the beginning automatically,I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.newSnapView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentOffset.x, (-1) * self.scrollView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];
```

should work.

Comment: ... what do you mean by the beginning? Does it need to go all the way to the left too?

Comment: it will not move up to the photo you uploaded,but it will move up to some where..

Comment: What's `(-1) * self.scrollView.contentInset.top`?

Comment: @LordZsolt It's so that the content is always at the top of the scroll view, even if a content inset is specified. That code compensates for the top content inset.